# Compute all outer products at once

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array `a` of shape `(n, k1)` and an array `b` of shape `(n, k2)`, I would like to compute all outer products of `a[i]` and `b[i]`. This

```
import numpy

n = 3

a = numpy.random.rand(n, 7)
b = numpy.random.rand(n, 11)

out = numpy.array([
    numpy.outer(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(n)
    ])

print(out.shape)  # (n, 7, 11)
```

does the trick, but it contains a Python loop which slows things down for large `n`.

Can the outer products be computed at once?

Comment: Which algorithm can calculate them without calculate n times? Rather to find another algorithm, I think creating a `numpy.array`  with fixed size and then using multiple processing to accelerate calculation is a better solution. For example, calculate `numpy.outer` with `numexpr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', a, b)
```

Or, using broadcasting,

```
a[:,:,np.newaxis] * b[:,np.newaxis,:]
```